# Can I use duplicate Schema.org 'url' in a table raw?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

If some `<td>` are URLs for the same product, do I need to mark each as `url`? Only one? Is it an error to mark them all?

Is the following code is valid?

```
<tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <td itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="myUrl.html">my product name</a></td>
  <td><a itemprop="url" href="myUrl.html"><img src="img.jpg" /></a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not useful to provide multiple `url` properties if the URL is the same.

Interested consumers learn that *this* `Product` has *this* `url`. When this `url` is provided multiple times, it’s not conceivable that it would change the consumer’s interpretation.

But it shouldn’t hurt either. It’s not an error.

Comment: I prefer to add the URL to both cells, because in the future a designer might ask to remove one of the cells . . .

Comment: @Atara: So, I would say: go with it. It’s not an error according to Microdata or Schema.org.